# How to increase maximum BitLocker password length?

Tags: bitlocker

How do I increase the maximum number of characters allowed in the BitLocker password? The current maximum is 20. I know that it's possible, because I have a second machine where the length is 8-256 characters.

- The group policy option "Allow enhanced PINs for startup" does not seem to have an effect
- The Powershell command `Add-BitLockerKeyProtector` is limited by the same restrictions.
- On my second machine, no other BitLocker group policies are enabled.
- I have Windows10 Pro, 21H2, 19044.1288.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What protection mode have you enabled? There's a difference between TPM+password and just password. `Get-BitLockerVolume` in powershell will give you the KeyProtectors in use.

Comment: @vidarlo It says `RecoveryPassword`+`TpmPin`. (On my second machine it states `Password`+`RecoveryPassword`). Maybe that's the source of the difference.
However, I can't find (in e.g. Group Policy) how to change that. Do you know?

Comment: Why do you want a longer password? The TPM includes brute force protection, so you'll not gain a lot by having a longer password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing different concepts:

- **BitLocker PIN** has maximum length of 20.
  Only its *minimum* length is modifiable in the Group Policy Editor.
- **BitLocker Password** has maximum length of 256 characters long.
- **BitLocker Recovery Password** has maximum length of 48 digits.

For password, you need to use
[Add-BitLockerKeyProtector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/add-bitlockerkeyprotector?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
with the parameters of `-PasswordProtector` and `-Password` like this:

```
$encpass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -String "yourpassword" -Force
Add-BitlockerKeyProtector -MountPoint C:\ -Password $encpass -PasswordProtector
```

You may also do this the traditional way:

```
manage-bde -protectors -add c: -password "yourpassword"
```

Comment: I only got around to trying it now, but unfortunately it doesn't work, the error being: `A password key protector cannot be added because a TPM protector exists on the drive`. And if I disable BitLocker, then you command runs fine but there's no effect: no password is required at startup.